# how does @HostListener does event binding?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular, just a question on how does @HostListener does event binding. We know that we can bind model data to an event as:

```
<button (click)="addProduct(newProduct)">Create</button>
```

where `addProduct` is a function in the corresponding component class.

But in custom directive class, we can do :

```
@HostListener("click")
triggerCustomEvent() {
   if (this.product != null) {            
       this.click.emit(this.product.category);
   }
}
```

but is that an event can only bind to a **component**'s method or properties? How come an event can also bind to custom directive's method as well?

Answer (score 0):

where is your custom directive?

I think yout directive dosen't set Angular Module.

If you wanna call that, use service.

see above.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YourCustomService {

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  customClickEvent(event) { 
   // ... do something
  }
}
```